# How to check if an HTML Element has on the of child elements as a link

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have to verify that an object is present on the page, and has a link.
object looks like this one:

```html
<td >
<input class="ng" type="checkbox"/>
<a  href="http://testsite.com ">67365853</a>
</td>
```

Here 'td'has an Anchortag as one of its child element, but using javascript, how to check if an anchortag 'a' is present or not?

any help would be appreciated!

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` on the element to find the first element within it that matches a CSS selector (it returns `null` if there is none). So assuming `theTd` refers to the `td` element, you can use

```
if (theTd.querySelector("a")) {
    // Yes, it has it
}
```

Example:

```js
var theTd = document.getElementById("theTd");
if (theTd.querySelector("a")) {
    console.log("Yes, it has it");
} else {
    console.log("No, it doesn't");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="theTd">
        <input class="ng" type="checkbox"/>
        <a  href="http://testsite.com ">67365853</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```